# SOAP Tracer in WSOEI is gone?

Tags: wso2-esb

New release. Instead of WSO2ESB server now WSOEI released. Good parts, less config has to be done to install DSS feature, it is builtin now.

Bad parts is SOAP Message Tracer is gone, Mediation-Tracer is gone. I thought they are moved to feature(repository) and need to install them separate, but repository(feature link) gone as well from Configure tab.

Does anyone know how to get them back?

Answer (score 0):

Find out how to install soaptracer on wso2ei-6.1.1. You must have apache ant and maven executable to be in $PATH

Copy underneath pom.xml to WSO2EI_BASEDIR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.wso2.mediation.tracer</groupId>
  <artifactId>mediation-tracer-feature-installation</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Mediation Tracer Feature</name>
  <url>http://wso2.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>carbon-p2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>feature-install</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>p2-profile-gen</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <profile>default</profile>
          <metadataRepository>http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/</metadataRepository>
          <artifactRepository>http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/</artifactRepository>
          <destination>${WSO_BASEDIR}/wso2/components</destination>
          <deleteOldProfileFiles>false</deleteOldProfileFiles>
          <features>
            <feature>
              <id>org.wso2.carbon.soaptracer.feature.group</id>
              <version>4.5.4</version>
            </feature>
          </features>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
        <replace token="false" value="true" dir="${WSO_BASEDIR}/wso2/components/default/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator">
          <include name="**/bundles.info"/>
        </replace>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
      <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
    <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven-releases-repository</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven-snapshots-repository</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

then set environment variable ${WSO_BASEDIR}

```
export WSO_BASEDIR=/home/path_to_wso2ei-6.1.1_folder
```

execute command

```
mvn clean install
```

if there are no errors in console, start wso2ei and you will see SoapTracer in carbon(admin) menu.